# Call an activity from another project

Tags: android

Hi have created two project `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`(both are empty) . I marked `ProjectA as Libray` and in `project B manifest file i added activity`

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.example.projecta.MainActivity"
</activity>
```

and in `activityB` i tried to `start activity of projectA` by

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.projecta.MainActivity");
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

but error comes `no activity found` to handle the intent 
Thanks

Comment: did u imported that class?

Comment: after making library did u added library in ur project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
no activity found  // because you have not added the Libray (ProjectA )
```

**so follow steps**

**1.**    `Right-click on your project B -> Properties`

**2.**    `In Android->Library section click Add` // add ProjectA

after adding projectA than click ok

Answer (score 0):

1. `com.example.projecta.MainActivity` is your Activity name.
2. `new Intent("your action");` it took action as the input.
3. So here you have two options define an action in you Manifest file and then call Intent on that action.
4. or Intent like this
          `Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

After you define an activity in your Manifest, you need to start it via `Intent` as you've tried, however you've implemented it wrongly in that you should be doing something along the lines of:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

You also need to actually add ProjectA to ProjectB as a library. Marking it as a library doesn't actually associate it with any other projects.